# Encoding required for Webrequest to retrieve Japanese characters

Tags: vb.net, encoding, httprequest

I need to know which encoding type to use for retrieving Japanese characters from a web page.
I have used following encoding for my web request(httpRequest). But, It's not working.

```
Dim receiveStream As Stream = hwresponse1.GetResponseStream()
Dim readStream As New StreamReader(receiveStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"))
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpWebResponse` object contains a property `CharacterSet` that will tell you what character set to use

Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.characterset.aspx for more details